# "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy" which jar is missing

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jboss7.x

Error shows **HibernateProxy** class is missing from .ear file.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy from [Module "deployment.abc.ear:main" from Service Module Loader
>
> Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy

Ear is deployed in **Jboss 7.0.0 EAP**

Which jar should I include either in **Eclipse build path** or project's **POM.xml**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have `org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy` in classpath, add this dependency to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Application is not deploying in jboss 7 server after adding this dependency in pom.xml. I am getting this error `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: abc] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory `

Comment: The container version of the Hibernate is given precedence over your application packaged version in Java EE conatiners. And hence the error.

To avoid this situation you need to control classloading explicitly and exclude the container library. read https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

Comment: Basically you will need to provide a jboss-deployment-structure.xml for fine grain control over dependencies.

~~~
 <jboss-deployment-structure>
        <deployment>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude container version of hibernate. By default its version 4, we want 
                    bundled version to load -->
                <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main" />
            </exclusions>
        </deployment>
    </jboss-deployment-structure>